# Train LSTM with probabilistic labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I´m currently working on a project where e.g. 10 users rated texted into two 2 categories. I´m trying to use the distibution as label for training a LSTM, e.g. if 8 out of 10 users voted for "yes" the label is 0.8.

I´m using the following model right now:

```
lstm = Sequential()
lstm.add(Embedding(number_unique_words, vector_size, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=max_len, trainable=False))
lstm.add(LSTM(64))
lstm.add(Dense(64, activation='sigmoid'))
lstm.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

lstm.compile(loss='mse',
             optimizer="adam",
             metrics=['acc'])

results = lstm.fit(x, 
                   y, 
                   batch_size=128, 
                   epochs=5, 
                   validation_split=0.4, 
                   shuffle=True)
```

The embedding_matrix is created by a 500-dimensional word2vec-model which indizes are created by a tokenizer. The input for the model is a tokenized comment then.

I already tried to vary the sizes and numbers of LSTM and hidden layers, used different optimizers and lrs, batch_size, epochs and activation-/loss-functions. The problem is that the acc always gets stuck at around 50% and the model predicts a constant value for all the test cases.

Does anyone have an idea which this is not working? Is it simply not possible to train an LSTM with probabilistic labels?

Comment: What do you mean by "probabilistic labels"?

Comment: like I said above, if 8 out of 10 users said it´s "yes", then the probabiliy that it´s "yes" is 0.8. So I´m training with the probability it´s "yes"

Comment: I believe the accuracy metric is inappropriate here. If your targets are continuous, how would you compute it? The Keras accuracy does not round your targets (see [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/metrics.py#L26)).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, using an r2_score now. let´s see how this works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my problem. I´ve been padding my tokenized comments in a "post" way, so I was appending 0s to bring them to a fixed length. Prepending 0s ("pre") to the comment changed the results completely. LSTM works way better with that!

For further reading check https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/ under pad_sequences and padding